# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'state_bottle_retail'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Hello I have this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', delimiter=';')
df.head()np.fromstring(df.state_bottle_retail.values.astype('|S7').tobytes().replace(b'$',b''), dtype='|S6')
```

And when I try to execute I get :

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'state_bottle_retail'
```

Any ideas to solve this ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to access a column which is done with square brackets like this df["column name"] and it returns series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the output from df.columns.values to make sure that state_bottle_retail is actually in there